# Formatação UTF-8 não funciona ao compilar código com maven no Intellij

Tags: maven, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, intellij

Boa tarde galera,

Seguinte, tenho um projeto Maven no Intellij configurado da seguinte forma:

[image: Intellij]

No pom tenho essas configs:

```
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

Mas quando eu faço o build e rodo o projeto as letras que estão no arquivo .properties aparecem assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe configurar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o problema, eu precisava marcar UTF-8 como default para arquivos properties:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]